# How to use HML Conditional Merge Fields in Salesforce Email Template?

Tags: email-template, lightning-email-template

I was trying to create a Lightning Email template and came across the need to conditionally display fields on the e-mail sent.

Searching the web regarding this issue drove me into this [Use HML Conditional Merge Fields in Pardot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_hml_conditional.htm&type=5) article.

However, when I try to apply the suggested syntax on Salesforce I am receiving a could not find helper: 'if' Java exception (print below)

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `{{#if ...}}{{/if}}` works for me in Salesforce Lightning, I am not using Pardot.

Is `Recipient` a custom object? In that case it should be `Recipient__c`.

Comment: Above example is from this documentation - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_hml_conditional.htm&type=5 Unfortunately it is not supported in Salesforce Lightning Email templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a feature only available in Pardot. Here is an idea to allow that in lightning templates https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003cICQAY

Comment: Welcome to the site Katie! This answer did get flagged for being a bit brief, but since it's your first on the site I think it's ok. Please do check out the tour if you've not done so: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour